# Find the first 3 decimal places of a definite integral

Tags: discrete-mathematics, definite-integrals

> $I(x)=\int_0^x \frac{\sin (t)}{t} \, dt$
>
> Find $I(1)$ correct to 3 decimal places

I thought that we just put $1$ instead of $x$ and we get $\frac{\sin 1}{1} = 0.841 $ but the answer is different.
Any ideas what is the correct way to solve it?

Comment: You're new here, so you don't know.  Please do not post unsearchable pictures of equations as the site's internal search mechanism cannot find them.  Instead typeset using *MathJax*.  It may be (almost certainly *is* the case) that your exact question has been posed and answered (or will be in the future).

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed to use the Maclaurin series of $\sin x$, divide by $x$ and integrate term-by-term:
$$\int_0^1\left(1-t^2/3!+t^4/5!-t^6/7!+\cdots\right)\,dt$$
$$=1-\frac1{3\cdot3!}+\frac1{5\cdot5!}-\frac1{7\cdot7!}+\dots$$
In this case, three terms are sufficient because the fourth is smaller than $\frac1{35000}$ in absolute value, so the answer is $0.946$.

Answer (score 0):

$$I(x)=\int_0^x \frac{\sin t}{t} \, dt$$

$$\sin t=t-\frac{t^3}{3!}+\frac{t^5}{5!}-\frac{t^7}{7!}+O\left(t^8\right)$$

$$\frac{\sin t}{t}=1-\frac{t^2}{3!}+\frac{t^4}{5!}-\frac{t^6}{7!}+O\left(t^7\right)$$

$$\int\frac{\sin t}{t}\,dt=t-\frac{t^3}{3\cdot 3!}+\frac{t^5}{5\cdot 5!}-\frac{t^7}{7\cdot 7!}+O(t^8)$$

Being an alternate series, the error is, in absolute value, less than the first term neglected, thus to have 3 correct decimal digits, the error must be less than $10^{-3}$.

Therefore we need to sum up to the $5$th power, because $\frac{1}{7\cdot 7!}\approx 0.00003$

So finally
$$\int_0^1\frac{\sin t}{t}\,dt=1-\frac{1}{18}+\frac{1}{600}=1703/1800\approx 0.946$$